# Where would I ask a question about what significance some words have in a song?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where would I ask a question about what significance certain words have in a old Spiritual song?

Answer (score 7):

If the question you have in mind is an interpretation-like question, then [**Literature Stack Exchange**](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) would be a good fit. (This site did not yet exist when the previous answers were posted.)

This type of question would be tagged with [`meaning`](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) and [`song-lyrics`](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-lyrics). At this moment, the site has [35 questions about meaning in song lyrics](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-lyrics+meaning).

Answer (score 5):

There is no site for this type of question at the moment, but there will be one very soon. The [Music Fans](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans) site is about to be launched into private beta.

As you can see from [this question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/are-question-about-lyrics-is-allowed), questions about the meaning of words in a song will be acceptable for the Music Fans site.

Comment: *Probably* will be allowed. As any new community, they may change scope and focus over time. Proposed questions on Area 51 aren't necessarily a guarantee of anything.

Comment: And just 14 hours later, Music Fans is in private beta.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the language of the words and make it sufficiently narrow, such a question may be on-topic on the SE for the corresponding language, if one exists. If you do not know it, language-identification [seems to be on-topic](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/465/1822) on [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

If your question is rather about the spiritual interpretation of the song, it may be on-topic on the SE for the respective religion, if one exists.

What of the above suggestions actually fits, if any, strongly depends on your actual question. So be careful to get an idea of the respective Stack Exchanges before asking, lest your question be closed.